# iphone image not getting uploaded

Tags: php, iphone, image

I am building a mobile website that captures a picture from iPhone using the following code in a form:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="display: block;">
```

This opens the camera nicely and allows me to click a picture. Till now all good.

On submit, I parse the entry using the following php code:

```
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
            if($check !== false) {
                //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;
            } else {
                $error[$i+1] = "File is not an image.";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
```

This works ok on PC but on iPhone this gives an error

```
"getimagesize():Filename cannot be empty in line 104".
```

line 104 is:

```
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: it seems like you are not getting file when form get submitted using iphone

Comment: yes looks like that .... but why is that happening? thats what I want help with

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like the problem was with my php.ini. The max upload size was set to 2M and my pics were more than 2M. Fixed that and it works like a charm!